# Parser Composition - a parser directive for Boost Spirit X3

Tags: c++, parsing, c++17

While exploring Boost Spirit X3 ([documentation](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/index.html)), I noticed that I couldn't find a [parser directive](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/quick_reference/directive.html) that composed parsers. I dug through the source code to see how the existing directives were made, and built one.

The idea is to have a parser `A` with an attribute that can be coerced to `std::string`, and a parser `B`; `compose(B)[A]` would run `B` on the output of `A`.

I'm a bit worried that I re-invented the wheel, or that what I did goes against the spirit of Spirit X3. I'm also worried about the efficiency or usability of it - I use `x3::parse` internally, which might also make error handling hard.

**compose.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace x3_extra {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    template <typename Primary, typename Secondary>
    class compose_directive
        : public x3::unary_parser<Primary, compose_directive<Primary, Secondary>>
    {
        Secondary secondary_;

    public:
        using base_type = x3::unary_parser<Primary, compose_directive<Primary, Secondary>>;
        static constexpr bool has_attribute = true;
        using attribute_type = typename x3::traits::attribute_of<Secondary, void>::type;

        template <typename TPrimary, typename TSecondary>
        compose_directive(TPrimary&& primary, TSecondary&& secondary)
            : base_type{std::forward<TPrimary>(primary)}
            , secondary_{std::forward<TSecondary>(secondary)}
        {}

        template <typename Iterator, typename Context, typename RContext, typename Attribute>
        bool parse(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last, Context const& context,
                   RContext& rcontext, Attribute& attr) const
        {
            std::string primaryResult;
            bool isPrimarySuccess
                = this->subject.parse(first, last, context, rcontext, primaryResult);
            if (!isPrimarySuccess) return false;

            auto secondaryFirst = primaryResult.begin();
            auto secondaryLast = primaryResult.end();

            attribute_type result;
            auto const isSecondarySuccess
                = x3::parse(secondaryFirst, secondaryLast, secondary_, result);
            if (!isSecondarySuccess) return false;
            if (secondaryFirst != secondaryLast) return false;

            x3::traits::move_to(result, attr);
            return true;
        }
    };

    template <typename Secondary>
    struct compose_gen
    {
        Secondary secondary;

        template <typename TPrimary>
        auto operator[](TPrimary&& primary) const&
        {
            return compose_directive<std::decay_t<TPrimary>, Secondary>{
                std::forward<TPrimary>(primary), secondary};
        }

        template <typename TPrimary>
        auto operator[](TPrimary&& primary) &&
        {
            return compose_directive<std::decay_t<TPrimary>, Secondary>{
                std::forward<TPrimary>(primary), std::move(secondary)};
        }
    };

    template <typename Secondary>
    auto compose(Secondary secondary)
    {
        return compose_gen<Secondary>{std::move(secondary)};
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
// parse ints with underscores ('_') in the middle
auto recognizeInt = x3::char_("0-9") >> *(*x3::lit('_') >> +x3::char_("0-9"));
// convert said strings into ints
auto parseInt = x3_extra::compose(x3::int_)[recognizeInt];
```

Comment: I believe there was a cppcon talk, which explained things very well. From what I remember, it should be just `>>` again.

Comment: @Incomputable yes michael caisse gave a cppcon talk (the only one I could find on X3, but there's a couple BoostCon ones). `>>` doesn't  "compose" parsers (like function composition), it "concatenates" parsers

Comment: Then I probably don't know what is the difference. The former could be appending, whereas the latter could be reordering? That is the only difference I can think of, and I never encountered the latter.

Comment: @Incomputable composition: `f (g (str))`. Concatenation: `f (str)` then `g (str-remaining)`

Comment: It looks like the `as<T>[]()[]` directive should do what I want, but it doesn't seem to exist

Comment: It also seems that this might be completely unneeded due to parser semantic actions

Answer (score 1):

@Justin, I'd suggest `filter_input` as a more descriptive name since
that's, in essence, what it does.  It changes the input to the
Secondary parser using the std::string attribute calculated from the
Primary parser.

Compose is too general a name since each operator in
`x3/operator/*.hpp` is, in effect, a composer of their sub-parsers.

@Justin, I'm mystified by your mention of `as<T>[]()[] directive`.  Is
it somehow related to `as<T>[]` mentioned
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819120/spirit-x3-how-to-get-attribute-type-to-match-rule-type?rq=1)?
If so, what are the arg to the trailing `()[]`?

In short, `compose` modifies the `input`; whereas `as<T>[p]` modifies the `attribute`.

BTW, first need to be restored to it's original value if either Primary or Secondary fails.

Comment: Hopefully my edited post satisfies the requirement to review the code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes I think you have thanks